# How should I understand 君の心配したらダメなの？

Tags: particle-の, parsing

Here's the text source: https://www.pixiv.net/novel/show.php?id=15490639.

> …ん、君今日はちゃんと来たんだ
> 　
> 昨日は、どうしたの？
> 　
> 風邪引いてたの？ふーん、そっか
>
> ちゃんと治ったの？
>
> ならよかった...って、なんでそんなに驚いた顔してるの？
>
> ...？**私が君の心配したらダメなの**？

I think it is 私 that is the subject of both 心配したら and ダメ, but what is this 君の心配 meant to be? I think it means to worry *about* 君 (like "Don't worry about ME") but how is this の particle used if it doesn't have the "possession meaning" (like 君's or [of 君] I mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the context, 君の心配 can mean either "someone's anxiety regarding you" or "your anxiety (about something)". In this context, it refers to the former. の is a multi-purpose noun-linking particle, and the possessive meaning is just one of the functions.

> 私が君の心配したらダメなの？
> Is it bad if I worry about you?

Similarly, 彼の手伝い can mean both "someone's help about him" and "his help", depending on the context. 彼の話 can mean both "the story about him" and "his story (about something)".

The subject of ダメ is not 私 but the described situation itself. You can rephrase the sentence verbosely like this:

> 私が君の心配したら、**それ**はダメなの？
> If I worry about you, is **it** bad?

But this それ(は) is normally omitted in Japanese.

Comment: Thanks, by "someone's help about him" do you mean "me helping him" for example?

Comment: @firuvi Yes, in other words, someone's helping hands toward him.